# ADF Copy Activity - Additional Columns Cannot Enter Function

Tags: sql-server, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data Factory Pipeline with a `For Each` Activity. This contains a `Copy Data` Activity which should insert into Azure Sql. I need to make use of the `Additional columns` feature but it refuses to let me select any value other than `$$FILEPATH`. It also will not let me type anything into the `VALUE` combo box.

[image]
Has anyone else hit this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is to add a column as you did and change its value by editing the code of the pipeline.

[image: Edit pipeline code in DF]

The problem is a display issue with the scrolling menu hidden by a layer (I have it too). It is maybe specific to some web browsers.

Comment: Thanks Xavier. The bug is present in Chrome and Edge but works ok in Firefox